# How to override w3.css for table border

Tags: css

I have a page where I need to display borders within a table and I'm using w3.css, this has the following:

```
table,th,td{border:none}
```

I have my own css file and have tried:

```
table,th,td{border:1  !important}
```

With and without "!important", after doing some searches I have also tried:

```
$("table").removeAttr('style').css("border","1");
$("th").removeAttr('style').css("border","1");
$("td").removeAttr('style').css("border","1");
```

I have tried the above with .table, .th, .td and have tried "1px" too.

I know that I can change the w3.css by removing the border settings and it works just fine, however, I would prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`border` is a shorthand property for `border-type`, `border-width`, and `border-color`. You need all three properties.

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I was missing the solid..., I now have table,th,td {border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;} as a style in the body for just the one page.  Thank you very much.